# Unable to deploy a VM by AzurePowerShell some powershell module conflict

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Seems to be a fairly straight forward task but having challenges and unable to understand what is exactly the issue?

Aim: To provision VMs by ARM templates

Step 1. Login to Azure - Interactively

Step 2. Select the subscription

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Step 3. Create resource group

Step 4. Create the deployment:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName arm-template
 -TemplateFile azuredeploy.json -TemplateParameterFile .\azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

However, I get an error like below

```
WARNING: AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same script or
runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm
 modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM
modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide.
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : The 'New-AzResourceGroupDeployment' command was found in the module 'Az.Resources', but the module
could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Az.Resources'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName arm-template -Templa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-AzResourceGroupDeployment:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

Hence, I ran the command:

```
PS E:\OnlyOnMyPC\azure-quickstart-templates\active-directory-new-domain> Import-Module Az.Resources
WARNING: AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same script or
runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm
 modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM
modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide.
Import-Module : AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same
script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove
all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az
and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module Az.Resources
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (AzureRM.Profile...igration-guide.:String) [Import-Module], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used
   in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' c
  mdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbo
 oks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide.,Microsoft.Power
Shell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Whatever you do, either uninstall or load module, this doesn't seems to work.

Comment: try to run `Enable-AzureRmAlias` before your running az command.

Comment: I am running Azure PowerShell not Azure CLI commands Sir, would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you run AzureRm and Az commands in the same session, you could run `Enable-AzureRmAlias` to enable AzureRM compatibility aliases. Or, it's recommended to use all the scripts supporting az module on Azure Powershell, such as change  `Select-AzureRmSubscription` to [Set-AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-2.5.0).

You could get more details from [Migrate Azure PowerShell from AzureRM to Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-2.5.0)

Comment: Yep, got it! Perfect, understood what mistake I was doing.

Comment: @learner There is no such command `Select-AzSubscription` for Az module, your option is to use `Set-AzContext` or `Enable-AzureRmAlias` first as mentioned.